# Windows Update and Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, windows-update, windows-sbs-2011

We have a Windows SBS2011 that runs an instance of Windows Server 2008 in Hyper-V.

When I check for windows updates in SBS2011, it offers to install the August Security Update for Windows Server 2008 (KB4034664).

Connecting to the 2008 and search for updates there doesn't yield the same result and all I get is an optional update.

Can someone elaborate why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBS 2011 is based on Server 2008 R2 and Exchange 2010.

So it's normal behaviour.